# In-memory logging

Tags: linux, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning a log file into a sort of circular buffer](https://serverfault.com/questions/133320/turning-a-log-file-into-a-sort-of-circular-buffer)

I have a daemon application that prints to stdout/stderr its logs. I am looking for a way to keep the last N lines of log **in memory**, and access them on demand, ideally with something simple like cat. This logs don't have to be persisted to disk.

Basically I'd love to be able to do something like:

```
./mydaemon.sh | memlog 100 mydaemonlog &
```

and then, afterwards:

```
cat /some/path/here/mydaemonlog
```

and I would get the last 100 lines of log, and then it would keep printing the log as it gets piped in the `mydaemonlog` file.

Is there some tool that is able to do what `memlog` is doing in the example above?

Comment: Is necessary to have N lines of log in memory? Or you want a solution to write the log to the disk ?

Comment: @Sacx I don't need them persistent or on disk. I could write them on disk and the perform log rotation, but it seems hopelessly inelegant.

Comment: @MadHatter you're right. Flagged as duplicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might output logs to /dev/shm and then use tail to get last n lines.

```
./mydaemon.sh >/dev/shm/log
tail -100 /dev/shm/log
```

Comment: Won't `/dev/shm/log` grow unbounded?

Comment: Yes, you'll need another script that monitors file size and truncates the file if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have in-memory sqlite database. The script managing it can make sure only 100 rows are on there at a time.